# pass parameters to groovy function

Tags: methods, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i want to build groovy (jenkinsfile) function to send emails.
function is used all over the code with different body but same "frame"
how can i call function with different body every time?

code looks like this

```
def email (){
    emailext subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
    body: 'you can access your VM with ssh ${FILE,path="/tmp/ip.txt"}',
    recipientProviders: [
        [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
    ], 
    replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
    to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i call function with different body every time?

Instead of this...

```
def email (){
    emailext subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
    body: 'you can access your VM with ssh ${FILE,path="/tmp/ip.txt"}',
    recipientProviders: [
        [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
    ], 
    replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
    to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
}
```

You could do this...

```
def email (String body){
    emailext subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
    body: body,
    recipientProviders: [
        [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
        [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']
    ], 
    replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
    to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS'
}
```

Comment: i did just that but it didnt worked before. anyway its working now! thanks for your answer

Comment: It is difficult to say why it didn't work before, but I am glad you got it working!